# File format and extension do not match

Tags: php, excel

I'm using the [php-export-data](https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data) library to export some data to an excel document.

I've initialized, added rows and finalized the document as per example and it generates a usable `.xls` file as expected but when I open it Excel 2010 throws a warning message saying `the file format and extension of xls don't match`.

The file is still usable and can be opened fine but as this is for a client I would much prefer for the warning to not show up at all.

The code I use to initialize, add rows and finalize the document.

```
$mailing_list = $event->getMailingList(); //returns an array

$exporter = new ExportDataExcel('browser', 'mailing_list.xls');
$exporter->initialize();

foreach($mailing_list as $mail){
    $exporter->addRow($mail);
}

$exporter->finalize();
```

When looking at the Microsoft documentation about this error it comes down to `.xls` files being renamed to `.xlsx` files and vice versa. I've tried using `mailing_list.xlsx` instead of `mailing_list.xls` but then Excel can't open the file.

I haven't changed anything to the library so maybe the problem lays there?

Comment: Does "save as" in excel suggest what file extension it actually is?

Comment: @Ericit saves as a `.xml` file. also the option form the dropdown by 'save as' says 'XML-worksheet 2003'

Comment: This is exactly what it is. As in https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data mentioned "export data in CSV, TSV, or Excel XML (aka SpreadsheeML) format to a file or directly to the browser". So either you live with that warning or you use a library which can really export XLS and/or XLSX. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel for example.

Comment: @AxelRichter could you write that up in an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning appears because the file extension *.xls is different from the content which is XML.

As in https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data mentioned, this library will "export data in CSV, TSV, or Excel XML (aka SpreadsheeML) format to a file or directly to the browser".

So the real content type of its exports will be XML and not XLS or XLSX. If you name the file *.xml and open this *.xml with Excel then the warning will disapear.  But then you can't be sure that this file is opened in Excel by double click. It will not if there is another application set as the default application for *.xml files.

So either you live with that warning or name the file *.xml or you use a library which can really export XLS and/or XLSX. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel for example.

Answer (score 1):

`*.xlsx` files can only be opened with Excel 2007 or later by default. If your version of Excel is older than this, then you can download and install the [Microsoft Office compatibility pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=3).

Looking at the comments above the [`ExportDataExcel` class](https://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data/blob/master/php-export-data.class.php), the format of the file is called SpreadsheetML. Unfortunately, it seems the correct extension for files of this type is probably `*.xml` which will not open in Excel by default. The comments mention that you can get around this issue by giving the file a `*.xls` extension, but that this will bring up the warning you get.

Comment: I have office 2010, and shouldn't `.xls` files (which this is) just open on any version of Excel?

Comment: But as stated before, when i use `.xlsx` instead of `.xls` it wont open at all, not even in Office 2010 which for all I know supports `.xlsx`

Comment: @LiamdeHaas See my edits. It doesn't really look like there's a nice way to get around this issue.

Comment: I just noticed that, thats unfortunate. Do you perhaps have a suggestion for a different library?

Comment: I've used the [PHP_Excel library](https://github.com/oliverschwarz/php-excel) (mentioned in the comments as the basis for the library you're using) in the past when generating Excel files. I believe that library can export as a `*.xls` file correctly.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. Also found out by a bit of googling that `.xls` files are in a binary format and `.xlsx` files are basically a zip archive with a bunch of files. PHP_excel still generates a `xml` file. I'll look further to find a solution.